# Search all record where the document date is below the selected date from date picker

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, date

I want to fetch and display all the record where the document date is below the date selected. Let says i pick a date from date picker 2016/09/28, means it will display all the record which is below the selected date.

```
SELECT * From `bill` WHERE bill_date <= '".$from."'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$selDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from));
// convert the selected date to mysql date format

SELECT * From `bill` WHERE bill_date <= '".$selDate."';
```

**Note:** If the bill_date is of type datetime than extract date portion using date() function and than put the condition on it.

Comment: the bill_date type is date not datetime.. i tried the sample that you give but it still showing the 2016/09/15 record where bill_date <= '2016-09-14'

Comment: done settle with it.. query problem when im using inner join

Comment: Please explain?

Comment: something wrong with my query where im using inner join with alot of table and it caused duplicate and i remove some unrelated table from my query.